# How do I automatically login in a user after the initial login?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

After a user logs in how do I keep them logged in even if the app is terminated? Currently the user can login, but when they end the app, they have to login again. Instead I want them to be logged in even if the app is ended. Below is the code for logging a user in.

```
 @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = self.usernameField.text
    let password = self.passwordField.text


    if(username!.utf16.count) < 4 || (password!.utf16.count < 5){

    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Username must be greater then 4 and Password must be greater then 5", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()

    }else{

        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username!, password: password!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((user) != nil) {

                //var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                //alert.show()



                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)


                })

            }else {

                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            }



        })

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `PFUser.currentUser()` after launching the app again?

Example in `viewDidAppear`:

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

if currentUser == nil {
     // log in logic

} else {
     // user is logged in

}
```

Comment: It says the current user is nil.

Comment: May try the provided PFLogInViewController ?